# How can I completely prevent firefox from showing the address bar in fullscreen mode

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, address-bar

In firefox, when going to *fullscreen mode* by pressing `F11`, the address bar disappears, which is what I want. However, when I move the mouse to the top of the screen, the address bar becomes visible again. This is distracting. So, I'd like to get completely rid of the address bar as long as I am in *fullscreen mode*.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On new Firefox v.71 currently on Nightly (Beta) you can add --kiosk when running to avoid all bars (navigation and tabs)

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly
https://www.ghacks.net/2019/10/07/firefox-71-new-kiosk-mode-for-the-browser/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac OS X.

This Add-on solved my problem: [Fullscreen+ for OS X](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/fullscreen-plus/)

It hides the address bar in full screen mode, when You move the mouse to the top od the screen no address bar or tabs are displayed, just the OS X system Icons - see  [animated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05GzP.gif)